# Count length of occurence of successive Nones and number of times that succession occurs

Tags: python, list

I have a list `r = [1,2,3,None,None,4,None,5]` I want to know the number of times the None occur and the length. This should give me:

- [2, 1] and 2

---

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def compute_stats():
    r = [1,2,3,None,None,4,None,5]
    length = []
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(r):
        if r[i] == None:
            j = i
            l = 0
            while j < len(r) and r[j] == None:   
                l += 1
                j += 1

            length.append(l)
            counter+= 1
            i = j + 1
        else:
            i += 1
    print str(r) +" length: " + str(length) +" counter " + str(counter)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    compute_stats()
```

---

as output I am getting the following

```
 [1, 2, 3, None, None, 4, None, 5] length: [2, 1] counter 2
```

---

The code works good. But is there a more beautiful way to do it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.groupby()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to both group the consecutive `None` values, and to count the group length:

```
[sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(input) if k is None]
```

Since `g` is a iterator of unknown length, I used `sum()` to avoid materialising that into a list; that could be quite memory intensive otherwise. If you are 100% certain that your groups of consecutive `None` objects is small (a few hundred at most) it *may* be faster to just use `len(list(g))` instead.

The default behaviour for `groupby()` is to produces groups of *identical objects*, so consecutive objects for which an `is` test is true. This is ideally suited for `None` values. For each group, a `k` and a dependent iterator are produced, with `k` set to the common group object; if `k` is `None` you know you have a series of consecutive `None` objects on hand.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive similar items, and filter out those whose group key is `not None`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1,2,3,None,None,4,None,5]
cnt = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lst) if k is None]
print(cnt, len(cnt))
# [2, 1], 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby

r = [1,2,3,None,None,4,None,5]

[len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(r) if k is None]
```